# Sorting my Rails Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My controller:

```
def index
  @unique_bug = Rating.find_by_sql("SELECT bug FROM ratings WHERE bug <> '' GROUP BY bug")
end
```

Rating Model:

```
  def self.metrics_bug_count(bug)
    count = where(bug:"#{bug}").count
    total = Rating.find_by_sql("SELECT bug FROM ratings WHERE bug <> ''").count
    percentage = (count.to_f/total.to_f * 100)
    return count, percentage
  end
```

My view:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
  <th><h3>Bug</h3></th>
  <th><h3>Total Occurrences</h3></th>
  <th><h3>Frequency</h3></th>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <%@unique_bug.each do |rating| %>
  <% count, percentage = Rating.metrics_bug_count(rating.bug)%>
  <td><p class="text-center"><h4><%= rating.bug.capitalize %></h4></p></td>
  <td><p class="text-center"><h4><%= count %></h4></p></td>
  <td><p class="text-center"><h4><%= number_to_percentage(percentage, :precision => 2)%></h4></p></td>
  </tr>
  <%end%>
  </table>
```

How can I make each row (Bug, Total, Frequency) to each be sortable? I watch the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?view=asciicast) episode on sortable tables, however the sorting there is done in the controller. How can I sort my table with a more complex find that is being performed in my model.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .order 
For example, Rating.order("count DESC").
Besides, I think you can avoid using find_by_mysql and use some rails method to do your query which is more readable and easier.
You can get the unique 1 using .uniq as well.

try have a look at
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html